# How to solve the cubic equation $-1.6x^3-2.1x^2-2.9x-0.3=0$

Tags: numerical-methods, cubics

Is there any method similar to the quadratic formula to solve the equation;

{$-1.6x^3-2.1x^2-2.9x-0.3=0$}

If not, how would I go about finding the solutions for cubic equations like these?

Comment: "Is there any method similar to the quadratic formula" Yes, but it's not pretty, and I don't think many people go around remembering it. Googling for "cubic formula" (like quadratic formula, only for cubic equations) might give you results.

Comment: For a quick answer, you can enter it in [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%9216x%5E3%E2%88%9221x%5E2%E2%88%9229x%E2%88%923%3D0) to see the approximate answer (-0.11172) and also ask for the exact form, which is horrendous.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thank you very much. How would I ask for the exact form?

Comment: @A-a Click on the "Exact form" button to the right of that section of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two good numerical methods, that give the answer as accurately as you like.

The first is the ' bisection method'. You start with a broad interval that contains a aolution, then narrow it down as finely as you like.

The second is 'Newton's Method'.  You need calculus to set it up, but then it is usually quicker than Bisection.  In this case, the key formula is

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{1.6x_n^3+2.1x_n^2+2.9x_n+0.3}{4.8
x_n^2+4.2x_n+2.9}$$

Start with any value for $x_1$. Calculate $x_2$ from $x_1$, then $x_3$ from $x_2$ and so on.  If you aren't unlucky, it will home in on a solution in three or four steps.

Comment: "it is usually quicker than Bisection" is an understatement. Bisection gives you one new correct decimal place every 3-4 iterations, although with a valid initial guess it is guaranteed to converge. Newton's (when it works) roughly doubles the number of correct digits each iteration, although it is not trivial to know what a good guess for starting point is.

Comment: If the denominator happens to equal zero, which happens from time to time, then it breaks

Comment: @Empty Also, if the function graph has a sigmoid shape around its root, then if the initial guess is on the flat part of the curve it might not converge. So bisection is more robust. But terribly slow.

Comment: @Arthur Sometimes, simplicity is preferred to efficiency. In most cases, I wouldn't care whether a computer would solve my equation in 0.0001 or 0.000001 seconds

Comment: @David Very true. But some times you need hundreds of thousands of them done, and then you do care about the difference between about a second and almost an hour. And some times, you just want to have fun and use cannons to kill mosquitoes.

Comment: .. and then spending an hour looking for the three where it didn't work